# Issue with pdf docs not showing up

Tags: vb.net, aspose.pdf

We recently wrote some code for a client using the Aspose.pdf library, on my system the pdf in question opened fine and most of the merge fields were filled in (we don't have the exact list of merge fields that they do).

They're telling me that on their system, some documents take 2-4 mins to open while others don't open at all.

What could be a possible cause of the document not opening at all?

My code is below:

```
' Load form
Dim doc As Aspose.Pdf.Document = New Aspose.Pdf.Document(sTemplateDir & sDocName)
'Get names of form fields
   Dim fields As Aspose.Pdf.InteractiveFeatures.Forms.Field() = doc.Form.Fields

   Dim sField As String
   Dim field As Aspose.Pdf.InteractiveFeatures.Forms.Field

If fields.Length > 0 Then
    For Each field In fields
    'Get name of field
    sField = field.FullName

    'If the merge field isn't valid then we'll just leave it and assume its a fill-in
         If nMergeCol.Contains(sField) And Not IsNothing(sField) Then
            field.Value = nMergeCol.Item(sField)
    End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, can you please share the resource PDF file in Aspose.Pdf product support forum, so that we can test the scenario and guide accordingly.
My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: @codewarior We have a theory on what the issue may be, it might actually be nothing with the above code but with the javascript within the pdf file itself. We're having the client look into it and get back to us.

Comment: @codewarior I say it might be the pdf's javascript because once we did get the full list of merge fields from the client and I ran it locally I experienced much the same issue they did. The document took about 30 mins to open though instead of not opening at all as they claimed (though I think if they waited long enough it would have opened). This led my colleagues to believe that it might be something with the pdf's javascript causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved! As we suspected, it was a problem with the client's Javascript within the pdf file. The problem was within the calculations the absolute value was being used (name.value). Once this was switched to the relative value (this.event.value) the pdf file began behaving correctly with the AsPose code.